# Very Basic query on logging in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have no programming background and I'm working on doing some very basic tasks with Powershell. Moving files and logging which files moved

I've tried using out-file and write-output none of which are working

```
Move-Item -Path $sourceDir\*.* -destination $destinationDir -force  | Out-File -filepath $Mylogpath -Append
```

I'm trying to move files from one server to another which I have working however I'd like to log the files I'm moving into a text file and date/time stamp them.

Any pointer gratefully accepted

Comment: that cmdlet has no default output. [*grin*] if you want it to tell you what it did, you will need to add the `-Verbose` parameter. otherwise, you will likely want to add explicit logging with one of the logging modules from the PSGallery.

Comment: i added the -verbose and it them gave me the below but didnt actually tell me the files it moved, im going to go have a look at the logging modules in PS Gallery. 'code' VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target "C:\testlog_012019.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target "C:\testlog_012019.txt" 'code'.

Comment: um ... you need to tell the item you want info about to give you verbose output. [*grin*] if you want to know what the `Move-Item` cmdlet is doing, add the parameter to THAT cmdlet. if you want such info on every thing, you can wrap it all in an advanced function and add the `[CmdeltBinding()]` option to it. that will pass a `-Verbose` call to everything in the function. ///// another two ideas - use the `*-Transcript` cmdlets OR enable script logging via GPO.

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey i added the -verbose to the correct cmdlet and used the *-Transcript to output all to a log. Working perfectly. Many Thanks

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

`Move-Item` by default does not output anything. To get an output of which files are moved, you can use the `-PassThru` parameter on `Move-Item`. This will then tell `Move-Item` to output the files it is moving:

```
Move-Item -Path $sourceDir\*.* -destination $destinationDir -force -PassThru | Out-File -filepath $Mylogpath -Append
```